# How to refresh Fields during activity inside a loop?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to download images and display them in a 5x5 grid, and I want each image to show up as soon as it's downloaded.

I have a `VerticalFieldManager`, and to it I add 5 `HorizontalFieldManager`s.  As I download each image (using `HttpConnection`), I convert it to a `Bitmap` then place it in a `BitmapField` then add the field to one of the `HorizontalFieldManager`s.

This works, except that I don't see any of the images until after all 25 have been downloaded, at which point I see them all.

I've tried calling `invalidate()` on everything involved after each image is downloaded, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing the download off the UI event thread?  If not, the download will block all UI updates until finished, which would explain the behavior you see.

**edit based on new information in comment:**

[HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) is blocking, so you need to do the IO operation on a thread outside of the UI thread.  Your application is downloading the images fast enough that blocking the UI thread isn't killing the whole app.  On a slow connection, your app would be killed by the OS while doing these downloads.

> This interface performs blocking Input and Output operations. An application will lock if an implementation of this interface opens a connection from within the main event thread. Prevent an application from locking by opening a connection from within a thread that is separate from the main event thread. SeeConnector for more information.

Comment: Yes, but each download is separate (I create and use a different HttpConnection object for each image).  What I'm trying to do is update the UI after each download completes. I assume I need to call something like Windows' DoEvents, which lets any pending UI-related messages to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

1) You should download and create `BitmapField` on a separate (non-UI) `Thread`.

2) When you have a BitmapField to add, then do something like this:

```java
final BitmapField b = ... // your code to get the BitmapField
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        yourContainer.add(b);
        yourContainer.invalidate(); // may not need this - try comment out
    }
});
```